# Timeseries queries with DAY granularity must have a start time that is the start of day (00:00:00) for the account's timezone

Tags: snapchat

I am trying to call Snapchat Marketing API for Ads stats with the end point through **Postman**

`https://adsapi.snapchat.com/v1/ads/<Some Ad ID>/stats?start_time=2019-08-10T00:00:00-04:00&end_time=2019-09-10T00:00:00-04:00&granularity=DAY`

Which is throwing as error as

> "Unsupported Stats Query: Timeseries queries with DAY granularity
>   must have a start time that is the start of day (00:00:00) for the
>   account's timezone. This account's timezone  is: Asia/Dubai"

I have tried all the possible combination of start time and end time in (ISO 8601) format.
does anyone know what might be the issue?

Comment: Gulf Standard Time is UTC+4, so have you tried `start_time=2019-08-10T00:00:00+04:00`?

Comment: Yes, UTC+4 throwing error as invalid start time

Comment: Did you URL-encode the string? A plus might get decoded to a space. Is there daylight savings adjustment to account for?

Answer (score 1):

Asia/Dubai is **+4** , but you used **-4**, so the start_time should be:

```
start_time=2019-08-10T00:00:00%2B04:00
```

You should encode `+` sign, otherwise it wouldn't work, + ~> %2B
The same should be on end_time, only one or two days after `start_time`